# Routing in Angular2 - GET 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

So I've made an app which was working great but then I've figured out that menubar on top with two links would be ok so I've followed this tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html but something is wrong. I can't get it working and there is this error:
GET http://localhost:3000/about/about.component 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:3000/home/home.component 404 (Not Found)

VSCode does not show any problems.

main file structure:

```
src
├───about
│ ├───about.component.html
│ ├───about.component.ts (and other .js and .js.map files)
├───app
│ ├───app.component.ts
│ ├───app.module.ts (and other .js and .js.map files...)
├───home
│ ├───home.component.html
│ ├───home.component.ts (other less relevant files)
```

in index.html I've added

app.module.ts:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'
...
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './../about/about.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './../home/home.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/home/home', //I've also tried home/home, home and so on
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '/about/about',
    component: AboutComponent,
  },
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    ....],
      declarations: [ AppComponent, AboutComponent, HomeComponent ],
    ....
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <nav>
      <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
      <a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

about.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'about',
  moduleId: module.id,
  template: `
  <p>ABOUT</p>
  `,
})

export class AboutComponent {

}
```

home.component.ts:

```
// imports

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.css'],
  providers: [HomeService],
})
export class HomeComponent {
// ...
}
```

The problem is probably connected to the routerLink but I've tried couple of different options and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

access these routes :

```
http://localhost:3000/about/

http://localhost:3000/home/
```

using this configuration :

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent,
      },
    ]
```

in your `HomeComponent` use relative path in `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` and put the `home.component.html` and `home.css` in the same folder with `HomeComponent`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.css'],
  providers: [HomeService],
})
export class HomeComponent {
// ...
}
```

Comment: I've tried it already. It doesn't work, it prompts exactly the same error in the console.

Comment: try it with no leading slashes in the path. see the update . show the errors if there ones

Comment: for path: 'home' and path: 'about' - `http://localhost:3000/about/about.component Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` and `http://localhost:3000/home/home.componentFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. For path: '/home' this error is exactly the same. Moreover there is another message: `message: "(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/home/home.component…"`

Comment: use these url : `http://localhost:3000/about/` , `http://localhost:3000/home/`
 as in my answer

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same errors when I'm trying to access :3000/about and /home.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138165/discussion-between-codddeer123-and-bougarfaoui-el-houcine).